# Elastic Report Data in Sheets - Pulling from Multiple Sheets (Same Spreadsheet)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I track trials with Google Sheets and have a tab for each customer.  In that sheet, there's a section for outstanding items.  Rather than having to look at every tab for outstanding items, I'm trying to roll up the 'Open' ones to a single summary page.

The summary page needs to be dynamic as items move from 'Open' to 'Closed', but also automatically account for new tabs being created for new customer trials that startup.  As well, the data might not always begin on A45, if I had to add stuff above, it may begin on A49, but I've got something in the line above to try and trigger off of (if possible)

Tried doing this with `FILTER` function, but that has issues.  I've either got to manually add each page, and have the proper amount of spacing, or with a concatenated filter, account for the exact cells in question.

Would love to see the Summary page be dynamic (or as dynamic as possible).
For existing trials, if I move something from 'Open' to 'Closed', it's removed from the summary page, and everything else moves up.  If something changes from 'Closed' back to 'Open', have it inserted accordingly and move everything down.
Best case scenario, when I copy my template file to a new tab for a new customer, that new tab automatically is included in the data set the summary report is pulled from.

---

#### UPDATED:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1759z0SoxANp--yt4HcI06-jpEt951ejJquYpwKE9V9E/edit?usp=sharing

here's the basis of what I'm trying to do but with some manual effort and errors.
You can see how the Issues data for Cust-A and B gets populated into the 'Outstanding Issues' tab courtesy of the `FILTER` function.  Unfortunately, if you were to change the status of item4 with customer A to 'Open', then the results page (A3) would go to `#REF!` status because it now needs 4 rows, and the 4th row is manually occupied by the next filter.  Also, the `FILTER` for A is different than B because Customer B has more contacts and success criteria.

I'd really like to have something that runs and looks at every sheet automatically, including when I add a new tab for Customer C.  This would prevent me from having to define the right amount of spaces needed along with re-doing the `FILTER` for every new tab.

Comment: thanks @player0, updated the initial post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to resolve this:

[image: 0]

---

delete everything in column **A** and paste this in **A3** cell:

```
={FILTER('CUST-A'!A18:O29, 'CUST-A'!F18:F29="Open");
  FILTER('CUST-B'!A20:O31, 'CUST-B'!F20:F31="Open")}
```

[image: 0]

---

but that is not enough and to counter further errors you need it like this:

```
=QUERY(
 {IFERROR(FILTER('CUST-A'!A18:O29, 'CUST-A'!F18:F29="Open"), 
 {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""});
  IFERROR(FILTER('CUST-B'!A20:O31, 'CUST-B'!F20:F31="Open"),
 {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""})}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

then you can do even this:

```
=QUERY(
 {IFERROR(FILTER('CUST-A'!A18:O29, 'CUST-A'!F18:F29="Open"), 
 {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""});
  IFERROR(FILTER('CUST-B'!A20:O31, 'CUST-B'!F20:F31="Open"),
 {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""});
  IFERROR(FILTER('CUST-C'!A20:O31, 'CUST-C'!F20:F31="Open"),
 {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""});
  IFERROR(FILTER('CUST-D'!A20:O31, 'CUST-D'!F20:F31="Open"),
 {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""});
  IFERROR(FILTER('CUST-E'!A20:O31, 'CUST-E'!F20:F31="Open"),
 {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""})}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: impressive.  could the interesting field of 'CUST-A'!F18:F29="Open" be changed to somewhere where we just look for "Open" in all of the E Column (and I risk a rogue entry)?

also, can the QUERY be written to allow for a future tab called "NEW-CUST" (or anything that deviates from the A->Z model) can automatically be added, or would it need to be re-written as new are added.  My goal was to somehow have it include the template, so that when I copy the template sheet to a new customer, that automatically gets updated in the QUERY. 

either way - impressive above, THANK YOU

Comment: as shown on examples the only possible way is to pre-write them in formula (CUST-C, CUST-D...). to have it auto-added in query you will need to do it with script eg. have the whole query writen in script that pre-detects sheetnames